# How to keep a userform filled out when working with the same document, but cleared when beginning a new one?

Tags: vba, ms-word, userform

This is my first time posting so thank you all for your help in advance. This is for VBA in Microsoft Word.

I am working on a template for my company that involves many, many little userforms to autopopulate data. When a user creates a new document from the Template (new report), no macros are prompted at open, but they can click specific macros from the ribbon to edit specific variables (i.e. the "Users" macro calls a form for the addresses of each intended user of the report, the "Value" form controls all the currency numbers, etc.). The report itself has restricted editing so variables can't be deleted on accident by the user.

I want these forms to be cleared and free the FIRST time they are opened from the new report, but to still hold the values put in by the user throughout working on the report. That way they can go back and edit if they realize they put in the wrong name, etc, without having to fill out the whole form again.

Each form basically uses the same macro in Module1, and within the forms, each TextBox then includes Instructional Text that disappears when clicked. Example code below.

Macro (in Module1 - copied from Greg Maxey ["Create & Employ a Userform"](https://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/create_employ_userform.html))

```
Sub frmExample()
    Dim oFrm As frmExample
    Set oFrm = New frmExample
    oFrm.Show
    Unload oFrm
    Set oFrm = Nothing
lbl_Exit:
    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

And then here is an example of how almost every text box works in each form code. Keep in mind there are up to 20 or so textboxes per userform but this is condensed heavily.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    With TextBox1
        .Forecolor = &HC0C0C0
        .Font.Italic = True
        .Text = "Instructional Text"
    End With
cmdCancel.SetFocus
lbl_Exit:
    Exit Sub
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_Enter()
    With TextBox1
        If .Text = "Instructional Text" Then
            .Forecolor = &H80000008
            .Text = ""
            .Font.Italic = False
        End If
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_AfterUpdate()
    With TextBox1
        If .Text = "" Then
            .ForeColor = &HC0C0C0
            .Text = "Instructional Text"
            .Font.Italic = True
        End If
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub cmdOkay_Click()
Dim oVars As Variables
Set oVars = ActiveDocument.Variables
    If TextBox1.Value = "Instructional Text" Then
        MsgBox "Please fill out all required fields.", vbOkOnly + vbExclamation
            If TextBox1.Value = "Instructional Text" Then
                TextBox1.ForeColor = &HFF
            End If
    Else
        oVars("varExample").Value = TextBox1.Value
        ActiveDocument.Fields.Update
        Set oVars = Nothing
        Me.Hide
    End If
End Sub
```

I think this has to be much more simple than I'm understanding right now but sometimes you just need somebody to tell you you're an idiot before you figure it out. I really, really like that instructional text thing and how it disappears at click so I don't want to lose that. I'm just thinking there could maybe be an additional Sub that works like UserForm_Initialize but instead only calls that when the user has already filled some things out. So after they click cmdOkay and want to go back to the form, all of their stuff is still there.

Any ideas? Thank you again!

Comment: The usual method would be to set a variable to indicate that a new document is being created and use that to indicate whether the form should be in its initialised state. That isn’t going to work for you though. However, as you appear to be writing the values to Document Variables you can simply read their values into the form each time it is initialised.

Comment: Take a look at "Taking it a small step further" on Graham Mayor's page: http://www.gmayor.com/Userform.htm which shows how to populate the form from variables, bookmarks, or content controls. When you have your code, please amend your question or post it as an answer.

Comment: One wonders why you're not using content controls positioned in the relevant locations within the document...

Comment: @macropod Is one really wondering? Because these reports are MASSIVE. Any text that is _repeated_ goes through the UserForms and DocVariables so it only has to be entered one time. Anything that is entered _only one time_ uses a content control and because the template is restricted, the user can just flip through those. This is to prevent mistakes like changing the currency once in the document but not elsewhere.

Comment: @TimothyRylatt CharlesKenyon and BigBen thank you very much for your suggestions. I will try to plug away through this tomorrow and will post an answer if I can figure it out... or at least get close.

Comment: @TempleGlascock - actually content controls are far better than using document variables. For any repeating text/values you use a CustomXML Part and mapped content controls. Then data only needs to be entered once and updates automatically throughout the document. So no need to update fields and no requirement for any UserForms.

Comment: «actually content controls are far better than using document variables» Agreed. Way better than using «many, many little userforms to autopopulate data» @TempleGlascock needs to learn how to use Word's features more effectively. With content controls, the problem simply wouldn't arise.